# Vim Airline plugin dont work properly on Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I am trying to configure [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) with my vim editor. (I am using **RHEL 7.1**) I installed the proper fonts from [powerline/fonts](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html#font-installation) documentation. then I clone the airline on my .vim/bundle/ directory.(I am using **pathogen**).
and then I customize my .vimrc file as follow:

```
" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif
" unicode symbols 
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols 
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
```

However my vim is still messed up
[image: Barline]
[image: Full image]

I looked at lots of Stackoverflow and other website about this issue and I tried all of their solutions but no luck.

Any help or suggestion?

This is what I see just with airline and fugitive vim plugin
[image]

Comment: Are you using any other plugins in parallel?

Comment: Yes I am

dwm.vim   
,nerdtree-git-plugin  
,vim-airline
,vim-endwise
,vim-gitgutter
,vim-javascript
,vim-rails
,vim-ruby
,nerdtree
,tern_for_vim
,vim-bundler
,vim-fugitive
,vim-indent-guides
,vim-javascript-syntax
,vim-rubocop
,YouCompleteMe

Comment: Have you tried deactivating some of them. Especially the ones changing the UI of vim?

Comment: I did try for most of them, not all of them such as YouCompleteMe

Comment: Please try to deactivate all of them except vim-powerline. That way you can make find out if side effects with any other plugin are causing the issue.

Comment: @iltempo I just added the new screen shot.

Comment: Looks as it's supposed to look like. Now start enabling your plugins one by one again to find the evil one.

Comment: is that utf-8 normal?

Comment: Use that plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @click: Are you sure you're using powerline patched fonts as default font for your terminal emulator?

Comment: @RoshanJossey: Well I download and install it according to the guide that I post it. is there a way to figure it out on vim that I is using that font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well After following @iltempo, recommendation, the evil plugin was end-wise. I created an issue on their Github account.